# Configure antd after create-react-app eject

Tags: reactjs, antd

My react app was created with create-react-app and I added And Design following:
https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app

I even customized some less vars using:
https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app#Customize-Theme

Now, I ejected my app but everything stopped working.

**EDIT1:**

The first error is that after ejecting, the scripts configured in package.json no longer works, as described here:
https://github.com/ant-design/create-react-app-antd/issues/10

What are the steps to configure antd after ejecting create-react-app?

Thanks

Comment: "but everything stopped working" does not provide any information. Explain the issue in detail. Also provide the source for your `config-overrides.js` and any other CRA files you have modified.

Comment: Did you run `npm run eject` or you are using `react-app-rewired`?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run `npm i react-scripts`.

This will install the missing dependency you need to make this work.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate your answer? What are the steps to make it work?

Comment: Thanks, long-time passed and I did not have time yet to confirm this solution.